# Print sentence based a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to print a sentence where 2 words change based on some conditions in a dictionary.

If the noun ends with the letter a, then the article having any "any" key with feminine and singular value is used in the sentence. BASICALLY I want to search for any "feminine" and "singular" in all keys. Once the key that has "female" and "singular" is found, then the key "la" is returned

```
article = {
  "il" : {
    "gender" : "male",
    "unit" : "singular"
  },
  "la" : {
    "gender" : "female",
    "unit" : "singular"
  },
  "le" : {
    "gender" : "female",
    "unit" : "plural"
  },
}
```

noun = {
"torta" : {
"genere" : "female",
"unità" : "singular"
}
}

```
if noun["noun"].endswith('a'):
  article is ['gender'] == ['female'] and ['unit'] == ['singular'] 

text = (f"{''.join(article)} {noun} {è buona}")

print(text)
```

Comment: An example output would help.

Comment: @MYousefi I wrote it in the question. Now I highlight it. The output is: La torta è buona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the strings were in Spanish, and some were in English, which caused issues with matching up the subject and the article. There were also some minor errors with the original code (e.g. passing a dictionary into an f-string). Correcting for these errors, we get the output (down to capitalization) by looping over `article_words.items()`:

```py
#article
article_words = {
  "il" : {
    "gender" : "male",
    "unit" : "singular"
  },
  "la" : {
    "gender" : "female",
    "unit" : "singular"
  },
  "le" : {
    "gender" : "female",
    "unit" : "plural"
  },
}

#noun
nouns = {
  "torta" : {
    "gender" : "female",
    "unit" : "singular"
  }
}    

subject = "torta"
if subject.endswith('a'):
    article = ""
    for key, value in article_words.items():
        if nouns[subject] == value:
            article = key
            break
    text = f"{article} {subject} è buona"
    print(text)
```

To get rid of the noun dictionary, you could do the following (see comments for discussion):

```py
endings = {
  "a" : {
    "gender" : "female",
    "unit" : "singular"
  }
}    

subject = "torta"
ending = None
for key, value in endings.items():
    if subject.endswith(key):
        ending = key
        break

if ending:
    article = ""
    for key, value in article_words.items():
        if endings[ending] == value:
            article = key
            break
    text = f"{article} {subject} è buona"
    print(text)
```

Comment: I thank you for the answer. That's what I was looking for. Unfortunately I was forced to modify the question, changing "noun". I no longer extract nouns from the dictionary, but from an SQL table where I can also have other words besides pie. In this case, how do you do it? I would need to get the same thing with "pie", but the difference with the question above is that noun (pie) is taken from a database table where I can have other words besides pie. Thank you

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know the details of your database. I would post a new question if I were you, because this is a question with little relation to the original.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you don't know the database details, just pretend that noun = cursor.fetchall () [0] is a column that contains only the word "torta". So what noun produces torta. The question is the same, nothing changes, just that "torta" is extracted from noun = cursor.fetchall () [0] and not from the dictionary. If you answer me of course I accept your answer as a solution and I also vote for you. Sorry for the change. Thank you

Comment: I noticed that you wrote if nouns [subject], so subject = "torta". That's right, but there is a small problem, which is that by doing so I am only tied to the word "torta", while I would like to apply the condition to any word that happens to me in the database.

Comment: Is `subject = "torta"` the issue? You can use `subject = cursor.fetchall()[0]` instead if you want to fetch the subject from a database. I might be misreading your question though.

Comment: Yes, I think it's fine as you said. If I use subject = cursor.fetchall () [0], I can remove the dictionary code of "noun" right?

Comment: If you have a way of reconstructing the `noun` dictionary from information in the database, then yes, you can.

Comment: I don't need the "noun" dictionary anymore. I don't have to use a dictionary for nouns anymore. All I need is the dictionary of "articles" and subject = cursor.fetchall () [0]. Your code says if nouns [subject], but I don't need the nouns dictionary anymore. How can I write now instead of if nouns [subject]? Thank you

Comment: Where would you get the information about the gender and unit of nouns then?

Comment: Simply if the noun ends with the letter A, then the key is searched based on the singular/plural and male/feminine values as I wrote in the question already at the beginning. BASICALLY I want to search for any "feminine" and "singular" in all keys. Once the key that has "female" and "singular" is found, then the key "la" is returned. I don't want a dictionary of the noun "torta", but I just need it to end with the letter A

Comment: You can create a dictionary mapping from suffixes to gender/unit information, and then find the suffix of a word by looping over the keys in the aforementioned dictionary.

Comment: I don't want a dictionary of the noun "torta", but I just need it to end with the letter A. But maybe I don't quite understand what you mean. What do you mean by your last comment? Can you show me an example of the code in your answer? Thank you

Comment: @Bobby Added to original answer.

Comment: Why should I do that excuse me? Why should I do that excuse me?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue with this approach is specifically.

Comment: I realized there was a typo in the original snippet; was that the issue?

Comment: No. It wasn't that. If you really want to help me, can you change your answer please so that I take your solution as an answer and vote you? Otherwise it is useless to continue to exchange comments. Thank you

Comment: It is not what I was looking for, but for your commitment imposed as resolved. It was useful to me, even if it is not what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you restructure article dictionary like:

```
article = { 'female': { 'singular': 'la', 'plural': 'le' },
            'male': { 'singular': 'il' }}
```

You can use it like this:

```
word = "torta"
if word.endswith('a'):
   article_ = article['female']['singular']
print(f"{article_} {word} e buena")
```

If you want to use the `noun` dictionary you can use:

```
article_ = article[nount[word]['gender']][noun[word]['unita']]
```

To use `article_words` as is:

```
article = next(filter(lambda x: article_words[x]['gender'] == 'female' and
                      article_words[x]['unit'] == 'singular', article_words.keys()))
```

will give you the article `'la'`

Comment: I like your code, but I would like to use my dictionary structure for "articles". Could you use the structure of the deectionary as I wrote in the question? Thank you P.S: I removed the noun dictionary

Comment: Thanks for the comment. apply it to your answer please? Reading the comment like this is not very clear to me unless applied to your response code. Thank you